# Delay in event in code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, delay

In my application I have a button to save some information. However, I would like to have a delay in the code before the last line is executed, so that the user could read the message that shows up before he gets redirected to the new page.

I know that doing this isn't at all an optimal way, but by some reasons (time, for example) I want to do it anyway.

So is it possible and if so, how could I do it?

Thanks in advance!

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Lots of code not relevant for the problem here

    Service service = new Service();
    service.SaveMovie(movie);

    successMessage.Visible = true;
    happyMessage.Text = "The movie was successfully added, now add some genres!";

    // Here I want a delay of 2 seconds before the next line is executed...

    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID), false);
}
```

Comment: They won't ever see the message text.  There will just be a 2-second delay before the response redirects.

Comment: You will need some JavaScript (jQuery) here.

Comment: Yeah, but I could change it to 5 or 10 seconds. The question is if it's possible and how to accomplish it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I actually use jQuery here by removing the div "successMessage" after 5 seconds. The problem is that that the redirection doesn't wait 5 seconds in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this on the client side. One alternative is this:

Define a `Javascript` function in the page called `redirect` as so:

```
function redirect(url)
{
   setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=url;} ,2000);
}


protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    // Lots of code not relevant for the problem here
    Service service = new Service();
    service.SaveMovie(movie);
    successMessage.Visible = true;
    happyMessage.Text = "The movie was successfully added, now add some genres!";

     // Here I want a delay of 2 seconds before the next line is executed...
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"somekey","redirect('"+String.Format("~/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID)+"');");

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. However, when implementing the code I get the following error message: "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(System.Type, string, string)". Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @JasonCraig I updated my answer. Try `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...)`.

Comment: Okey, thanks. The thing is that now I got the following error message instead: "The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context". :/

Comment: @JasonCraig LOL, well, es either ClientScriptManager or ClientScript. If you are using .NET 4.0, you should be able to do this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript but `this` is obviously not necessary so calling ClientScript should work if this code is inside a Page. If the code is inside a User Control, then you should be able to do `this.Page.ClientScript`

Comment: Oh, sorry. No it's not in Page, so this.Page... worked. However, when running my app the code isn't executed, instead the following is shown as text on the webpage: "redirect('~/Edit.aspx?id=53');" :S

Answer (score 0):

This will be easy if you are using Javascript. Use javascript will boost performance

```
Button_Click
{    

string js ="<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function()window.location.href="+String.Format("~/Edit.aspx?id={0}", movie.MovieID)+";} ,2000);</script>"
```

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(Page), "js", js, False)

```
}
```

possible duplicate of
[asp.net delay before response redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136402/asp-net-delay-before-response-redirect)

Comment: Thanks alot! However, I get compilation error in ClientScriptManager... "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(System.Type, string, string)". Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: This is wrong. You can't call System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) to achieve what the user wants. This will block the response for 5 seconds and then spit out whole HTML.

Comment: i think its possible to reduce 5000 to some low value

Comment: @Harie In fact, thanks for linking that other question. The answer provided by Rahul Sony is also wrong. I've downvoted it.

Comment: @lcarus so whats the problem if we are using Threading.Sleep() ?

Comment: @Harie You don't understand. You can reduce it to 1 sec if you want. the point is that the user wants to show a message and then wait before redirecting. If you call Thread.Sleep will block the response, nothing will be written until the second has elapsed. The user will then be redirected IMMEDIATELY before being able to see any message.

Comment: @Harie: No, as I wrote in the comment above I can't compile the code because of: "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(System.Type, string, string)"

:/

Comment: @Icarus: Yes, that's correct. I tried it but it "froze" everything for 5 seconds, i.e the js-code wasn't executed.